# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с решением задачи с использованием циклов?

Tags: javascript, циклы

-Дано натуральное число. Найти и вывести на страницу все его делители.

а)Определить количество его четных делителей

b)Найти сумму его четных делителей

Код:

```js
let naturalNum = +prompt('Введите любое натуральное число', '...');
document.write('Вы ввели число: ' + naturalNum + '.' + '<br /><br />');
for (let i = 2; i * 2 <= naturalNum; i++) {
  if (naturalNum % i == 0) {
    document.write(`Делитель этого числа: ${i}` + '<br /><br />');
  }
}
```

Comment: Давайте разбираться -  для этого нужен ваш код

Comment: цикл от 1 до указанного числа....... если число делится нацело на то, что сейчас на итерации - значит делится.......... чётные - те, что делятся на 2 без остатка.......осталось только это запрогать

Comment: let naturalNum = +prompt('Введите любое натуральное число','...');
document.write('Вы ввели число: ' + naturalNum + '.' + '<br /><br />');

for (let i = 2; i * 2 <= naturalNum; i++) {
    if (naturalNum % i == 0) {
        document.write(`Делитель этого числа: ${i}` + '<br /><br />');
    }
}

Comment: а вот дальше не пойму... то ли вложенность циклов!? и как правильно их описать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужен ещё один цикл. Вы и так уже проходитесь по делителям. Просто в момент вывода можно так же проверять, является ли оно четным (делится на 2 без остатка), и записывать в счетчики сумму и количетсво.

```js
let naturalNum = +prompt('Введите любое натуральное число', '...');
document.write(`Вы ввели число: ${naturalNum} <br /> <hr/>`);
let count = 0,
  summ = 0;
for (let i = 2; i * 2 <= naturalNum; i++) {
  if (naturalNum % i == 0) {
    document.write(`Делитель этого числа: ${i} <br /><br />`);

    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      count++;
      summ += i;
    }
  }
}

document.write(`<hr/> Количество четных делителей: ${count} <br /><br />`);
document.write(`Сумма четных делителей: ${summ} <br /><br />`);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @ДоляДенис Отметьте вопрос как решенный